# member variables and @var phpdoc type hinting

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc, type-hinting

I've been using inline @var declarations for type hinting PHP to use the prediction and reference jumping in Eclipse but what is the structure when it is a member variable like in the example below? (the below does not seem to work)

```
/* @var $this->obj AbcObj */
$this->obj = Factory::get(...);
```

*Assume a wide variety of object types can come out of the factory.

Answer (score 2):

In the class declaration that `$this` represents, if you have declared `$obj` as a class variable, then put a docblock on it:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var AbcObj
     */
    $obj = null;
}
```

That should give you exactly what you're after.  That inline `/** @var` thing was something that evolved out in the wild to give this behavior to local non-class variables, based on wanting that autocompletion that exists for class variables.